# Error Multi Login Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I try to make multi auth in laravel 5.4, finally after login, i want show that name of user use this code `{{ $show = auth:dokter()→username;
{{ $show }}`
but the error is "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::dokter(), may u can help me, please

Comment: make sure in `auth.php` set `'driver' => 'eloquent'`

Comment: In guards ? i already do that but in provider,

Comment: Wouldn't `\Auth::user()->username` work?

Comment: yeah its work, i have 2 guard user and dokter, if show user it works, but if i show dokter its error. you wanna see thats file ? may u can fix it

Comment: Have you made sure that all of your classes are autoloaded? running `composer dump-autoload` & `php artisan optimize` may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should use `Auth::user()->username` that should do the trick for you, but if you want to make sure that a specific guard is working, maybe wrap it like this (I am guessing you're doing this logic in your blade template):

```
@if (Auth::guard('doktor')->check())
    Auth::user()->username
@endif
```

The if statement will return true if the authenticated user has guard 'doktor', and if that returns true you can echo out their name.